# Preselect multiple ListView items

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ListView with SelectionMode Multiple

```
 <ListView x:Name="MarketsListView" SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

I can get an enumerable of selected items with

```
var selectedMarkets = MarketsListView.SelectedItems.OfType<Market>();
```

Now I want to load the Page with preselected items in this List. How can i set selected items in code? I tried the following where `markets` is a list of `Market` objects, but this does not work

```
foreach (var market in markets)
{
    MarketsListView.SelectedItems.Add(market);
}
```

> Is there any way to select multiple list items in code?

Comment: Your code is not enough to reproduce the issue, SelectedItems.Add should work just fine.

Comment: I realized that i was just adding new objects with the same values to the SelectedItems list and not references of the list objects. SelectedItems.Add works like you said, thank you!